# Is " stream video" a correct verb?

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to come up with a proper verb that fits in the following sentence

> The suggested solution to protect the store is to ***stream video*** the place live.

My question is Is "stream video" actually a verb? I know it is possible to rewrite the sentence or one can use surveillance camera as an alternative but I'm looking for a verb rather than paraphrasing the whole sentence.

Comment: My confusion is actually with the word *alive*. Do you mean "live video"?

Comment: @Era, yes. Sorry I think it is live rather alive. Or probably I don't need it at all.

Comment: You're looking for a single word that means "to set up a surveillance camera".

Comment: @TRomano, true.

Comment: There is a single word, "surveil", that means "to put under surveillance". I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: The *verb* is ***to stream***. The reason your example wouldn't be endorsed by most careful speakers is because when you *stream **video*** this is a transitive usage (where the *direct object* is "video"). If you're going to introduce an indirect object ("the place", here), it should be preceded by a preposition (usually, "to", but in this specific case, probably "from"). So the cited usage is "non-standard", but really that's par for the course in technological contexts where new concepts arise faster than the language itself can keep up with.

Comment: English is flexible enough so that you can use *stream video* as a verb, but the novelty of it may confuse people. What's wrong with just *video*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "stream video", but I don't know if it's exactly what you want. Streaming refers to the *transmittance* of video data, specifically when the video is downloading as you watch it (as opposed to downloading the entire video, then viewing it afterwards).

In the phrase "stream video", "video" is the object of "stream", it is not a compound verb. So you can't "Stream video the place". You could "stream live video from the place".

I think the word you want is "surveil". It's not by any means a common word, but it's a word.

Comment: Does "surveil" indicate using cameras? In my case, I want to emphasize on the visual feedback.

Comment: No, it has exactly the same connotation as "surveillance", i.e. it could be by cameras, by audio recording (a "bug" or "wire"), or by an actual person, such as a prison guard. You could say something like "surveil the place by live video".

Comment: Yes that what I thought. Probably "surveil" is not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Stream is the verb while video would be a noun as one could stream audio, video or any form of data into a location. "stream live video" may be the better phrase here as otherwise I'd suspect the phrase at the end should be "stream video to the place live" or "stream video of the place live" depending on if the place is meant as a location receiving the stream or meant as a location of what is in the stream.

Comment: They probably want *of* rather than *to*.